CUDA_HOME error even though CUDA_HOME is set
I was recently trying to run the neuralangelo program developed by nvidia labs and I ran into an error while setting up the conda environment:
Collecting git+https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/#subdirectory=bindings/torch (from -r C:\Users\shaun\Documents\neuralangelo\requirements.txt (line 3))
  Cloning https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ to c:\users\shaun\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ltveby0h
  Resolved https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ to commit 2ec562e853e6f482b5d09168705205f46358fb39
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Pip subprocess error:
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ 'C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ltveby0h'
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ltveby0h\bindings/torch\setup.py:5: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/ll
        from pkg_resources import parse_version
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ltveby0h\bindings/torch\setup.py", line 51, in <module>
          raise EnvironmentError("Unknown compute capability. Specify the target compute capabilities in the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES environment variable or install PyTorch with the CU)
      OSError: Unknown compute capability. Specify the target compute capabilities in the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES environment variable or install PyTorch with the CUDA backend to detec.
      Building PyTorch extension for tiny-cuda-nn version 1.7
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

I set up the CUDA_HOME variable in both my computer and the environment that I was running neuralangelo on but the errors keep happening and I am not sure why. Does anyone know a fix to this problem?

Specify the target compute capabilities in the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES environment variable or install PyTorch with the CUDA backend seems extremely clear. The build needs to know what GPU architecture(s) to include. Either explicitly tell it, or install the tools to let it determine it for you.

I agree with @talonmies. You have to figure out the architecture or the GPU. Lot of the GPU code can be optimized for the architecture and so you need to set the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=86 for example. This would set the architecture to Ampere 86. There is a full list of GPUs and arch to look up for you. Check this page
